# Removing smaller area which is less than 10000 inside vector?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I want to remove smaller area which is less than 10000 inside the vector.But the selected areas(smaller area) only remain after using Data Management>>Eliminate tool in ArcGIS10.1.

Which tool should be used?

Answer (score 2):

I would use "Definition Query" in the layer properties - right click on the layer in the table of contents, then select "Properties", then go to the "Definition Query" tab.

You can then build a SQL statement similar to the following: area > "10000". Where "area" is the column in the attribute table that you are trying to select that is greater than 10000. That will display only the polygons that have an area greater than 10000. If you need a new layer, you can then right click on that layer in the table of contents and export the data as a new layer.